# force an underscore in my search word

Tags: discussion

I want to search for the term "ACCESS_MASK" in SO.  I get 44 results most of which contain "access mask" (no underscore) or "accessmask" (no underscore), or the words "access" and "mask" somewhere in the text (no underscore connecting them).

Ok, I can open each of the 44 to find the ones that contain ACCESS_MASK.  But it would be nice if my underscore were observed during the search.

I guess I don't really have a question, do I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Google:

[https://www.google.com/search?q="access_mask"&sitesearch=stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22access_mark%22&sitesearch=stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions)

Comment: To search questions using Google directly from the search in the upper right corner, you can use this UserScript I wrote: [StackExchange Google Search](http://stackapps.com/questions/3182/stackexchange-google-search)